# LWC loadScript from static resource with export inside

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, static-resources

I have a js library that I created static resource for it:

The js library content (the calc.js file for example) like

```
export default calculate = function(x,y){return x+y;}
```

In LWC, I import the static resource like:

```
import calcLib from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/calcLib";
```

and load it up with:

```
loadScript(this, calcLib+"/js/calc.js")
        .then(() => {
            debugger;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          debugger;
          this.error = error;
        });
```

It's always failed loading the script with the message like:

```
WARNING: Failed to load script at /resource/165916882xxxx/calcLib/js/calc.js: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module [export declarations may only appear at top level of a module]
```

I have tried modified the library (the calc.js file) like removing export keyword and it load successfully.
I have many libraries in my system. Do I have to remove all export keyword to load them in LWC? It's really a nightmare. Is there another way to work around here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Components are compiled using something like rollup or webpack; the files delivered to the browser aren't the same scripts you upload or see in your IDE, at least not directly.

If you're using a static resource, you must "export" any properties you want using the `window` global object:

```
window.calculate = function(x,y){return x+y;}
```

Which you can then load:

```
import calcLib from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/calcLib";
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
```

...

```
scriptsLoaded = false;
async connectedCallback()
  await loadScript(this, calcLib);
  this.scriptsLoaded = true;
}
```

Note that the functions won't be available until `scriptsLoaded` is `true`. If you don't want to wait for these functions to be available, you have an alternative; you can move your files to a Service Component.

By doing this, it can be bundled with everything else and loaded, and you can use your scripts verbatim without any modification; you'll just need to move your files into the lwc directory under a component folder.

First, create a new component, for example, `utils`:

```
sfdx force:lightning:component:create --type lwc -n utils -d force-app/main/default/lwc
```

Then, delete the HTML file, such that you only have two files left, `utils.js` and `utils.js-meta.xml`.

Now, you can copy paste your code, verbatim, into the `utils.js` file.

```
export default calculate = function(x,y){return x+y;}
```

Which you can then import:

```
import calcLib from 'c/utils';
```

You can also copy many files into this component, and then in your utils.js file, you can export those functions:

```
export * from './calc';
```

Comment: There are limitations on the style of export supported in LWC (or at least there were when I last checked) which can mean you need to modify the source code to fit with LWC.

Comment: @PhilW Yes, there were limitations in previous releases, but I'm unaware of any unsupported export statements in this release. I'm actively working on a project that keeps evolving as LWC and JS improve.